# change the text Hint in the date piker

Tags: android, material-design

Any one knows how can i change the hint in this part of the material date picker in Android?

[Actual text hint format image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OTPC.png)

I am expecting to have a different date format text hint, similar to this
[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fO3Jt.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`MaterialDatePicker.Builder#setTextInputFormat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/datepicker/MaterialDatePicker.Builder#setTextInputFormat(java.text.SimpleDateFormat)) to control the date format. It was added in 1.8.0 ([release notes](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.8.0)).